# Tabbed Page OnBackButtonPressed in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, back-button

How to navigate between the tabbed pages while back button is clicked in xamarin forms

Answer (score 0):

**Try this you need to override OnBackButtonPressed event and also maintain a stack**

Generally navigation in Tabbed pages are done by clicking on Tabs itself.

```
protected Stack<Page> TabStack { get; private set; } = new Stack<Page>();

protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
{

    // current page
    var page = CurrentPage;
    if (page != null)
    {
        // Push the page onto the stack
        TabStack.Push(page);
    }

    base.OnCurrentPageChanged();            
}

protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{

    // Go to previous page in the stack. First, 
    //pop off the top page since this represents the
    // current page we are on.
    if (TabStack.Any())
    {
        TabStack.Pop();
    }

    // Check if we have any pages left
    if (TabStack.Any())
    {
        // Pop off the next page and Launch it
        CurrentPage = TabStack.Pop();
        // Return true to indicate we handled this scenario
        return true;
    }

    // We don't have any more pages in the stack so do the default 
   //funcationlity
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ...I Will check it

Comment: No . it doesn't

Comment: Im using this Bottom Bar renderer https://asyncawait.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/bottom-menu-for-xamarin-forms-android/

Comment: ok @nandha wait for few minutes let me create an example for you and then i'll share the code